# Using oauth2 Service Account within a Java-Webapplication

Tags: oauth-2.0, tomcat7

I'm develop a simple HTML5-Client for DFA-Reporting. For this I use a Google OAuth Service account, which works pretty fine on a client solution. But know I've been in trouble when I want to read the .p12-File within my Webapplication-Backend. Following problem appears:

```
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big.
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:561)
```

The application runs on an embedded Tomcat (Spring Boot) and I'm using the following approach the read to file:

```
   File p12File = new java.io.File(this.getClass().getResource("/test-privatekey.p12").toURI());
   this.httpTransport =  GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12File)
                    .build();
```

The Client-Solutions read the p12-File like this:

```
File p12File = new java.io.File("test-privatekey.p12");
```

Did anybody have a solution, or an solution-idea for this problem?

Many thanks and greetings from Berlin

Answer (score 0):

Exclude p12 files in your POM.

```
<build>   
     ...
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>                
          <configuration>
            <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
              <nonFilteredFileExtension>p12</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>       
     </plugins>  
</build>
```